# Loading JQuery files gives errors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im using a pre-made template and modifying it for my needs for my project. Looking in the console I get a number of errors I have no idea how to fix. This is what it looks like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
    at jquery.fileupload.js:91
    at jquery.fileupload.js:25
    at jquery.fileupload.js:27
jquery.fileupload-image.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileupload')
    at jquery.fileupload-image.js:46
    at jquery.fileupload-image.js:40
    at jquery.fileupload-image.js:42
jquery.fileupload-audio.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileupload')
    at jquery.fileupload-audio.js:34
    at jquery.fileupload-audio.js:28
    at jquery.fileupload-audio.js:30
jquery.fileupload-video.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileupload')
    at jquery.fileupload-video.js:34
    at jquery.fileupload-video.js:28
    at jquery.fileupload-video.js:30
jquery.fileupload-validate.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileupload')
    at jquery.fileupload-validate.js:30
    at jquery.fileupload-validate.js:24
    at jquery.fileupload-validate.js:26
jquery.fileupload-ui.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileupload')
    at jquery.fileupload-ui.js:43
    at jquery.fileupload-ui.js:38
    at jquery.fileupload-ui.js:40

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tooltip')
    at v1.js:77
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (v1.js:88)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3557)
    at process (jquery.js:3625)
```

Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: Without looking at the code directly, it is difficult to determine exactly what the cause of this issue is. The errors are stating that there are undefined variables which are being accessed, this may be a case of some JS files loading before other dependencies, I would recommend consulting with the makers of the template/relevant documentation.

Comment: Hi! Please improve your question by [creating a minimal reprocible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and trying to explain to us the steps you are taking that lead to these errors.

Comment: It's likely the order of the dependencies is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You must be using [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and so, should add the the [jquery.ui.widget.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js) before calling the jquery.fileupload.js file

Take a look at the [Mandatory requirements](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#mandatory-requirements) section within the readme.md

> #### Mandatory requirements
>
> - jQuery v1.7+
> - **jQuery UI widget factory v1.9+** (included): Required for the basic File Upload plugin, but very lightweight without any other dependencies from the jQuery UI suite.
> - jQuery Iframe Transport plugin (included): Required for browsers without XHR file upload support.